# Incorrect Directory Index

Tags: configuration, apache-httpd, wordpress, htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am attempting to load as the default DirectoryIndex home.html, but the site keeps jumping to index.php. Website is built on WordPress.

**httpd.conf**

```
DirectoryIndex index.html home.html index.php index.html.var
```

**.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^home\.html$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your httpd.conf is correct.  Your issue here is that he default home page for WordPress is index.php.  Therefore index.html will never load

Comment: How can I change the default page to home.html?

Comment: You cant, or you break WordPress

Comment: I'm not getting how the WordPress software is overriding httpd.conf and .htaccess.

Comment: WordPress will not work if the default page is index.php.  It doesn't matter which one is listed 1st in your configuration because Apache doesn't "Use the listed 1st item 1st."  It chooses one in the list.  Since your site is using WordPress, then index.php is found 1st

Comment: See Answer Below

Comment: I ended up simply creating a page template.Has been a while since working with WordPress; forgot how simple it was.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using an HTML Splash Page, you can do the following:

1. Rename index.html to default.html
2. Upload default.html to the same directory as index.php
3. Add default.html to your DirectoryIndex values.

FWIW, this issue has existed since WordPress 2.7.  See [this support forum post](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/indexhtml) (Last Post, Page 2)